# Convert float to LPCWSTR/LPWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi

[win 32 C++]

I don't know how to convert float to LPCWSTR/LPWSTR or LPCWSTR <-> LPWSTR

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
...
float f = 45.56;
wstringstream wss;
wss << f;
// wss.str().c_str() returns LPCWSTR
cout << wss.str() << endl;
...
```

Comment: Or in C via "w" printf variants: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647550%28VS.85%29.aspx. I prefer this method though.

Answer (score 2):

The native Win32 API doesn't have any functions for printing floating point values, but there's a more recent addition called **strsafe** which has [StringCchPrintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647541(VS.85).aspx)

```
TCHAR buffer[24];
StringCchPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), "%f", float_value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it looks complicated and the simple above does same job :)